# Nullpointerexception after loading a checkbox in ListView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

i have used this android code to get the choice of a checkbox:

```
View view_web = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3)).getChildAt(2);
CheckBox input_web = (CheckBox)view_web.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
```

I also have an EditText field. Without an input, it works. But if there is an input, it crashes. Do you know, what might cause this error?

My logcat:

```
06-20 17:20:23.123: E/AndroidRuntime(670): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 17:20:23.123: E/AndroidRuntime(670): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 17:20:23.123: E/AndroidRuntime(670):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onMenuItemSelected(MainActivity.java:140)
06-20 17:20:23.123: E/AndroidRuntime(670):
```

The line with the checkbox is the code who causes the error.

This is how i try to get the code of EditText:

```
View view_a =( (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1)).getChildAt(0);
EditText input_a = (EditText)view_a.findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
```

Code of the method:

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
View view_a =( (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1)).getChildAt(0);
EditText input_a = (EditText)view_a.findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
View view_b =( (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1)).getChildAt(1);
EditText input_b = (EditText)view_b.findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
....
View view_web = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3)).getChildAt(0);
CheckBox input_web = (CheckBox)view_web.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);        
View view_sms = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3)).getChildAt(1);
CheckBox input_sms = (CheckBox)view_sms.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
```

I only get nullpointerexception if the edittext is not empty.
            ...

Comment: Did you put these after or before setContentView(main)? They need to be after it.

Comment: some more context is needed before we can figure out the issue!

Comment: Why are you using `getChildAt(0)`? You are getting the ListView without a problem with this: `(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1)`, then getting a child view at a certain index, which may or may not be something you want.

Comment: I don't think `getChild(0)` is the right way to find the EditText that you want. Please post more code with the whole `onMenuItemSelected` method.

Comment: We need more code. Btw you cannot get the text view the way you're trying to.

Comment: Don't use `getChildAt()` on a `ListView` to get items. Use the `ListAdapter` that's set on the `ListView` to get items, like `adapter.getItem(position)`.

Comment: If i would try getItem, i will geht the content of the textviews. But each row has this format: textview ... edittext. So how can i get access to the edittext?